# ラズベリーパイによる音声認識（音声会話）に関するエラー

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#マイク0番からの入力を受ける。一定時間(RECROD_SECONDS)だけ録音し、ファイル名：mono.wavで保存する。

import pyaudio
import sys
import time
import wave
import requests
import os
import json
import subprocess

def recognize():
    url = "https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/amiVoice/v1/recognize?APIKEY={}".format(APIKEY)
    files = {"a": open(PATH, 'rb'), "v":"on"}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
    message = r.json()['text']
    print message
    return message

def dialogue(message="こんにちは"):
    url = "https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/dialogue/v1/dialogue?APIKEY={}".format(APIKEY)
    payload = {
      "utt": message,
      "context": "",
      "nickname": "光",
      "nickname_y": "ヒカリ",
      "sex": "女",
      "bloodtype": "B",
      "birthdateY": "1997",
      "birthdateM": "5",
      "birthdateD": "30",
      "age": "16",
      "constellations": "双子座",
      "place": "東京",
      "mode": "dialog",
      "t":20
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
    print r.json()['utt']
    return r.json()['utt']
    def talk(message="こんにちは",card=1,device=0):      
        res = subprocess.check_output('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunk = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    PATH = '/var/tmp/tmp.wav'
    APIKEY='48316b555a686253622f6f47746b386a77624b437a65754d69466173495041415747647a482f524a756543' #DocomoAPI Key
    CARD = 1 #OUTPUTの指定
    DEVICE = 0 #OUTPUTの指定
    #サンプリングレート、マイク性能に依存
    RATE = 48000
    #録音時間
    RECORD_SECONDS = input('Please input recoding time>>>')

    #pyaudio
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    #マイク0番を設定
    input_device_index = 0
    #マイクからデータ取得
    stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                    channels = CHANNELS,
                    rate = RATE,
                    input = True,
                    frames_per_buffer = chunk)
    all = []
    for i in range(0, RATE / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        all.append(data)

    stream.close()    
    data = ''.join(all)                    
    out = wave.open(PATH,'w')
    out.setnchannels(1) #mono
    out.setsampwidth(2) #16bits
    out.setframerate(RATE)
    out.writeframes(data)
    out.close()

    p.terminate()

    message = recognize()
    talk_message = dialogue(message)
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
```

上のpythonスクリプトを実行すると

```
Please input recoding time>>>3
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started

こんにちは！今日もたくさん話そう
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 88, in <module>
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
NameError: name 'talk' is not defined
```

というふうにエラーになってしまします
どうやって解決できるでしょうか

#### 詳細情報

このスクリプトに関係するAPIまたはアプリ

- requests (PythonのHTTPライブラリ)
- pyaudio (pythonでマイク入力)
- AquesTalkPi (合成音声)
- docomo雑談API (会話するためのAPI)
- docomo音声認識API (音声を認識してTEXTに変換するAPI)*NTTじゃない方のやつ

#### 環境

- raspberry pi 2 model B
- Python 2.7.9

#### 参考サイト

- [簡単にできる！音声認識と音声合成を使ってRaspberrypiと会話](http://qiita.com/kinpira/items/75513eaab6eed19da9a3#%E5%BD%B9%E8%80%85)

#### スクリプトの出処（上のスクリプトは若干変えてます）

- [dialogue_test.py（GithubGist)](https://gist.github.com/yusukeyamatani/d3197434e90512b5875d)

#### P.S.

APIKeyとレート（RATE)は正しく入力しているはずです

下の方からインデントを改善したほうがいいと言われますした
しかしインデントを正しく(サンプルコードに）合わせると

```
こんにちはー。海へ行きたいね
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 89, in <module>
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 44, in talk
    res = subprocess.check_output('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " ' + message.encode('utf-8') + ' " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi " こんにちはー。海へ行きたいね " | aplay -Dhw:{},{}' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

というようなエラーが出てきました
どうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージを読みましょう。88行目で`NameError: name 'talk' is not defined`ということなので`talk`という関数がありません。参考にされたというリンクのコードには42-43行に`talk`という関数が書かれていますが、あなたのコードではインデントのレベルが合ってないので、トップレベルから見えなくなっています。Pythonはオフサイドルールを採用しているのでインデントが影響します。

Comment: エラーの原因は `res = subprocess.check_output('/home/pi/aquestalkpi/AquesTalkPi ...` の部分で `.format(card, device)` が抜けているためです。

Comment: 分かりました。ありがとうございます

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題となっているエラーメッセージはここです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dialogue_test.py", line 88, in <module>
    talk(talk_message, CARD, DEVICE)
NameError: name 'talk' is not defined
```

最終行を和訳すると「'talk' という名前は定義されていません」です。

ひとまず現れているエラーの原因はこのエラーメッセージに書かれているとおりです。関数 `talk` が定義されているスコープがおかしく、関数呼び出ししている所からは見えていません。
Python はインデントによってスコープが変わってしまうので、そのことに注意しつつ定義を書き換えてください。
より詳しくは、参考になさった [yusukeyamatani/dialogue_test.py](https://gist.github.com/yusukeyamatani/d3197434e90512b5875d) と質問文中のプログラムを見比べていただければ分かるかと思います。